# How to solve NuGet error in visual studio

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nuget

i am receiving below error while installing selenium web driver in visual studio 2012. Please help.

"The schema version of 'Selenium.WebDriver' is incompatible with version 2.0.30625.9003 of NuGet. Please upgrade NuGet to the latest version from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=213942"

No clue what to do

i am receiving below error while installing selenium web driver in visual studio 2012. Please help.

"The schema version of 'Selenium.WebDriver' is incompatible with version 2.0.30625.9003 of NuGet. Please upgrade NuGet to the latest version from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=213942"

solve this issue

Comment: On the nuget page it goes back only until VS2013... Is there a specific reason why you use such an outdated version of visual studio?
If you update your studio, your nuget problem will be gone too.

Comment: You can either upgrade visual studio or download the latest distribution of nuget from nuget site (https://www.nuget.org/downloads). As the link mentions "Latest NuGet releases are delivered as part of Visual Studio updates.".

Comment: Thank you for your comment. in my office 2012 is generally used. But now i have requested to install 2017. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Update NuGet by going to Go to Tools -> Extension and updates -> there under updates you will find Nuget Package Manager